# AutoComplete TextBox Multiple Entries Comma Separated

Tags: wpf, xaml, autocomplete, textbox

Is there any way of making a TextBox widget that autocompletes, but allows you to autocomplete each time you have a separator, for example a ",".

Let's say I want to write a list of fruits in a textbox, for example:

"Apples, Pears"

...and my list of valid entries is let's say [ Apples, Pears, Oranges, Clementines ]
so each time I type a comma it resets the autocompletion, so that for example "A" was autocompleted to "Apples", but then typing a comma and then typing "Pe"  will auto-complete to "Pears".

Big ask I know, but just in case...

Comment: I don't think i understand you want to type "Pears, " and then autocomplete? Autocomplete to what?

Comment: So for example when I typed "Apples" it autocompleted, fine. But now when I type a comma I want it to reset the autocompletion, so typing "Pe" will autocomplete to "Pears".

Comment: Ok now i understand, you want the ',' to be ignored. Well we can't answer that because we don't know what kind of autocomplete control you use. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox) its a very neat AutocompleteTextbox, it should be varly easy to extend it for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look at this [Autocomplete Textbox](http://wpfactb.codeplex.com/) from there you use Regular Expressions to split the input text with commas and separate them and just populate again the control to whatever the result was. Hope it helps!